# Create background italic shades

Tags: html, css, photoshop, rectangles

I want to achieve the following:
On the background of my webpage I want to have repeated italic shades (rectangles?) in Blue, red and white using HTML and CSS.

Example on following website: http://clubbrugge.be/nl/

I kwow photoshop so if nessecary I can create the rectangles there.

Comment: Here's a tutorial to teach you how: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-diagonal-lines-with-css--net-20763

Comment: use CSS3 feature `transform`

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
body {
background-image: url("paper.gif");
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) for repeated background

Answer (score 0):

give background image and repeat vertically

```
.background{
  background-image: url('yourfolder/image.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

you can use it in body `<body class="background">` or in any div